# Is latest version of jar support older version jar

Tags: httpclient, compatibility

Is **httpclient-4.5.2.jar** backward compatible with **httpclient-4.3.6.jar**?
Same question also for **httpcore-4.4.4.jar** with **httpcore-4.3.3.jar**?

I have to use a newer version for supporting some functionality. but is there any impact of my older code?
Is those jar version controlling working conventional way for backward compatibility support like java JDK?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no. For minor upgrades (4.3.3 to 4.3.4) things usually work, but when you go from 4.3 to 4.5 you can expect changes. See [release notes](https://archive.apache.org/dist/httpcomponents/httpclient/RELEASE_NOTES-4.5.x.txt) for hints about what you can expect.

Having said that, if you can compile without errors you are usually safe!

Comment: I actually wanted to know if older jar have one class that have a method, then newer jar should have that method or possibility to delete that method?

Comment: There are no guarantees. The newer jar may have removed the method.